# EOF caught while checking if connected phpmailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, starttls

```
    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'myhost';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'myusername';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 1060;                                    // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'test');
    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML


    $mail->addAddress('test@gmail.com');    // Add a recipient  

    for($i=0;$i<1;$i++){
      $mail->Subject    = "test bulk email ".$i;
      $mail->Body       = "this is email ".$i;


      if(!$mail->Send()) 
      {
          $error_message = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
      }
}

echo $error_message;
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

> Connection: opened 2018-03-05 09:24:25    SERVER -> CLIENT: 2018-03-05 09:24:25   SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected 2018-03-05 09:24:25 Connection: closed 2018-03-05 09:24:25  SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an unusual port number for SMTP submission, so check you have the right one for your host. It would usually be 587 when using `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`.

You're setting a gmail from address while sending through another host; that will cause you to fail SPF checks and your messages will either be blocked or spam filtered.

If you want to send to a list, follow [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) - your code contains some mistakes that will probably result in duplicate messages.

Comment: Actually, im not sending through an gmail from address, Im sending it from the same host. The port that I'm using is right. I need to use StartTLS. I'm using the older version of PHPmailer because I don't know how to install the newest version, I dont know what composer and that stuff is.

Comment: Uh, you are using a gmail from address: `$mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'test');`. You're here to learn, right? So go [install composer](https://getcomposer.org), or alternatively, follow the installation instructions in the PHPMailer readme which tells you how to use the latest version without composer.

Comment: I wrote that email as an example, Im really using another email not from gmail. I would like to know how composer works and how to use it.

Comment: Yeah, downloaded it but still looks like braille for me -.-